# webscraper.io only scraping 18 product links only instead of scraping all 60 product links in the website

Tags: web-scraping, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to scarp all the product links from this site using wesbscraper.io chrome extension- https://www.namshi.com/uae-en/women-clothing-dresses-casual/new-products/

Here each pages has 60 product links and i want to scrape all links.

For this I followed the pagination selector method given in the link - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FO_i5JT8Glk

And, in the metadata space I entered this - [https://www.namshi.com/uae-en/women-clothing-dresses-casual/new-products/?page=[1-20]](https://www.namshi.com/uae-en/women-clothing-dresses-casual/new-products/?page=%5B1-20%5D)

Now I am able to scrape or download the excel sheet with product links but from all the pages only first 18 product links are being scraped. That means for 20 pages (each pages having 60 product links), I am only received 360 product link, whereas I should be receiving about 1200.

PLEASE ! Can somebody help me here that what I am doing wrong ? I am stuck with this issue from last some days. As I am not experienced with coding much, I am looking for simple solution. Something which can be solved using free extension or software. Some click and run solution.

TIA.